# package system broken (14.04)

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I tried installing Google Earth this morning using this code:

Terminal Commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libxext6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 lsb-core
wget -O google-earth64.deb http://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-earth64.deb
rm google-earth64.deb
```

It did not appear to install (can't find it when I search anyway), and I am now getting a package system broken error when I try to run software updates.
I am new to ubuntu, so am looking for detailed help with this.
Thanks!

Comment: ok, tried that...here's what I got:Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package –

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo apt-get -f install` to install the missing dependencies and try again.